# how to implement typescript function overload

Tags: typescript

How to implement  typescript  function overload ?

```
interface Fn <T>{
  (payload: string): T;
  (payload: string, a: T): T;
}

let fn: Fn<number> =  function(a: string, b: number) {
  return b
}
```

report `Type '(a: string, b: number) => string' is not assignable to type 'Fn<number>'.Vetur(2322)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to satisfy an interface with multiple (i.e., overloaded) call signatures, a function's implementation must be able to handle *all* such signatures.  If `fn` is a `Fn<number>`, then you must be able to call it like this:

```
fn("someString"); // first overload
fn("someString", 1234); // second overload
```

But the implementation

```
function (a: string, b: number) {
  return b 
}
```

does not satisfy the first overload (since `b` would be `undefined`), and so is not assignable to `Fn<number>`.

Instead, you should consider coming up with an implementation compatible with both call signatures.  For example:

```
let fn: Fn<number> = function (a: string, b?: number) {
  return b ?? a.length
}
```

Here, the implementation requires its first parameter  `a` to be a `string` and takes an *optional* second parameter `b` of type `number`.  Since `b` might be `undefined` and you have to return a `number`, you can't just return `b` directly.  In the above I return `b` unless it is `undefined`, in which case I return `a.length`.  This is always a `number` and the compiler can verify the assignment as valid.

---

Note: there is a complication in situations where the overloaded call signatures have different return types.  Unless your function expression's implementation returns the [*intersection*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) of all the return types, the compiler will not be able to verify type safety and will error, so you'll need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
interface OtherFn {
  (payload: string): string;
  (payload: string, a: number): number;
}

let fn2: OtherFn = (a: string, b?: number) => b ?? a; // error!
//  ~~~ <-- string | number not assignable to string

console.log(fn2("abc").toUpperCase()) // ABC
console.log(fn2("abc", Math.PI).toFixed(2)) // 3.14
```

Here you can see that `fn2` does satisfy both call signatures in `OtherFn`, but the compiler is unable to verify it because of the different return types.  You'll need a type assertion if you want to do this with function expressions:

```
let fn3 = ((a: string, b?: number) => b ?? a) as OtherFn; // okay
```

or you can abandon function expressions and use function statements, which are checked more loosely, allowing the return type to be the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) of all the call signatures return types:

```
function fn4(payload: string): string;
function fn4(payload: string, a: number): number;
function fn4(a: string, b?: number) {
  return b ?? a;
}
```

which can be seen to satisfy `OtherFn` despite not being manually annotated as such.

```
let fn5: OtherFn = fn4; // okay
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0&ts=4.0.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIgDwBUB8yDeAUMsgBQAOcAngDYD2cAJgFzIDOYUoA5gJStYA3MTKVaDFu048ANMjgD+yIYQC+hQjACuIBGGB0Q8hEnJh0AOS0BbAEbRSMEK3QYQN+1By8CIp6QAiNjprCABlaRBuAN5BZAB6eOQYYCgOZDoAN2h6Jj8QQODQiK4ogLkARgAmAGYAFliEpLYIBENGDOyoXMY1DRoIMGTnNEx3O2g8AF5knT0DI1IFKVLuOVsAflZxzx8iEihBrSgjW2QNjfkAOgGosAALPsI2kGCBm7puRwKA+4gaejlZDVGq8RqJYG1Z6GN4QD5ffy-f6AsFxCEAVmQGixoEgsEQKAA8g9oOhfCQKNQeqwOKslLSeMIKWJqStZPJth5oEodtBhOpCAMhk4qqxiX8oGSZksaZE1shNpyJlAfFM8GcLvI0UloFA6FAAISECHIAB+5uQGAAtFa2VFkAAfZC8qDOuhDOBsNjAbggOC2AbIMB0O3cDQvWHw75VQL+hAxK7BgCq5HI0AAwp6IKQwU1kABBABC6ehrzo73oCJAMYCcaBAFk4A8rgAFACSvETdFQwAAHhBGKQqrmITUrhU6v1BsMashpTLQ+sts6uSq5+rzpc4D5PchxaSQNqMgBragabS6fSGYZ1SniJiyumPxmaOZXoxOW8siTPqJyZYujyq7CBe8zXp+C4Mn+CrLoB5LIIcYDHKcm5ak8QrDOiYokpKRgzJ+R50KeVCEEAA)

Answer (score 1):

In order for both of those overloads to apply to `fn`, you have to make `b` optional in your implementation.  When you do that, you'll see a different error because our type says that we must return a `number`, so returning `b` when `b` might be `undefined` doesn't cut it.  We can either set a default value for `b`, or return some default value within the body of the function.

```
let fn: Fn<number> =  function(a: string, b: number = 0) {
  return b;
}
```

```
let fn: Fn<number> =  function(a: string, b?: number) {
  return b === undefined ? 0 : b;
}
```